# Accessing OS X built in dictionary lookup in Firefox

Tags: macos, trackpad, multi-touch, dictionary

I am really frustrated that Firefox does not provide the three-finger-tap lookup operation is in built in OS X. What is baffling me is that it supports other gestures such as two finger swipes and taps. So why not the 3 finger tap dictionary ?

Is this possible to actually implement ? Or is it because access to in built dictionary and trackpad is blocked by OS ? How can I start looking at this problem ?

Comment: On force touch will directly open lookup.

Answer (score 22):

As of now (Dec 1 2014), although the option is not present in right-click menu, three-finger dictionary lookup works perfectly fine in my Firefox (Developer Edition 35)

Also there have been certain plugins which help you look up words in dictionary through right click. For example https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/look-up-in-dictionary-7261/

EDIT (Oct 2017): I'm now using the new e10s Firefox and the dictionary lookup still works. You don't need any plugin, just tap with three fingers or press `Control + Cmd + D`.

Comment: Triple-finger lookup works for me (Firefox 39), but there's a subtle bug. I first need to click somewhere on the page. Without this first single click, triple-finger gesture is ignored on newly opened pages. Details: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687026#c26

Comment: CTRL+CMD+D works for me. tested on firefox 70.0 on OSX 10.15

Comment: @ash One force touch works OK. I set my trackpad to "Force click with one finger to Look up & data detectors"

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately looks like this is still an open bug as of today.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687026

Comment: yes I am aware of that. but i was thinking of fixing it and hence want a point to start...

Answer (score 3):

[Firefox bug #687026](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687026) regarding 10.7 - 10.10 was fixed Jan 2016.

[Firefox bug #1212527](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1212527) regarding 10.11 was fixed in May 2016. Firefox 49+ has the fix.

Working as expected on 10.11 and 10.12.

Comment: Confirming. Once enabled in System Preferences, it works as expected in Firefox under macOS Sierra/Firefox 49+.

Comment: @dr.nixon How did you do that? Could you explain with more details, please?

Comment: System preferences -> trackpad -> point and click -> look up & data detectors.

Answer (score 1):

One can open the MacOS dictionary by typing `dict://word-in-question` in the address bar.

This extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/macos-dictionary-lookup/ adds a menu item to do it. In order for it to work, you need to do the above process manually, and allow Firefox to open the dictionary app.