# Monterey's password manager in Firefox/other apps

Tags: password, firefox, monterey

How do I use the new Monterey password manager when I want to log in to a website in Firefox? I don't want to go to the System Preferences to look up the password, I want that it automatically pops up when I want to login into a Firefox/other application site and I can choose the desired account.

Comment: You can't - the app has to implement access to the keychain and Firefox and Chrome have not done this - they want to be cross platform ie Android and Windows and have implemented their own password manager. I use a third party one (1password) that works in iPhone Safari and Firefox to solve this issue

Comment: In the past it seemed to take three years for Firefox development to [add initial support for things like Apple dictionary](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/15565/) lookup or [fix bugs in that function for OS upgrades](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/129755/). Hopefully this patch arrives sooner since iCloud Keychain is very attractive feature wise at a very popular price point.

Answer (score 2):

As Ezekiel mentioned, as of macOS Sonoma, an extension exists for [**Chromium-based browsers**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/icloud-passwords/pejdijmoenmkgeppbflobdenhhabjlaj).

The **Microsoft Edge** version has since been released and is [available for download](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/icloud-passwords/mfbcdcnpokpoajjciilocoachedjkima).

Additionally, for **Mozilla Firefox**, an unofficial extension can now be [installed](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/icloud-passwords/).
Disclaimer: I'm the author. Source code available on [GitHub](https://github.com/au2001/icloud-passwords-firefox).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone has developed or released a product to code this.

It’s likely you need Firefox development (volunteer or paid) to update their app or make a plug in. I have not examined the Firefox code recently, but Apple has documentation on how third party developers can call for password auto fill.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view

At the bottom, there is a warning:

> If you use a custom input view for a security code input text field, iOS cannot display the necessary AutoFill UI.

And also the requirements for html pages to summon the UIKit function.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element

If the pages you visit meet the above requirements and work on safari you may be stuck waiting for Firefox to support this or have to use an alternate system like https://1password.com/ which ships extensions / plug-in for Firefox to add similar support.

Comment: Could there be a possibility of someone implementing this as a third-party-addon/software without waiting for official support from Firefox/Apple?

Comment: Could someone use Apple public and/or private API to [modify Firefox](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/contributing/directory_structure.html)  - absolutely! Who will do the work and test it and support it is always the question. As you see I didn’t find the macOS documentation and  had to link to iOS docs. I don’t know if that’s because apple hasn’t written it and/or the API are still changing and/or are private. Time will tell for sure….

Answer (score 0):

In macOS Sonoma (available only as a public beta as of writing), the iCloud Passwords extension is now available for macOS. Previously this was only available for Windows.

Chrome Web Store: [iCloud Passwords](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/icloud-passwords/pejdijmoenmkgeppbflobdenhhabjlaj)

This extension is also coming to Microsoft Edge, but no version has been announced for Firefox at this time.