# Firefox: Is there a way to add a "look up" option to right-click 'context' menu?

Tags: firefox, dictionary, contextual-menu

I use my laptop with an external keyboard, mouse and monitor when I am at home. In order to look up a word when in Firefox I have to select it and then lean forward and do a 3-finger tap on the trackpad. It would be more convenient if I could select "look up" on a page from the right-click context menu brought up using the mouse (as Chrome allows).

Is there anyway I can add this feature to Firefox? I've tried a few FF plug-ins but I haven't found one which works the way I want.

---

**Dictionary brought up through trackpad tap**

[image]

---

**Firefox context menu**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Look Up has a system-wide key command, if that's any use to you.

Default is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>D</kbd> .

You just hover the mouse over the word you want, no click needed.

I tested it works in Firefox.

[image: Keyboard settings in System Preferences displaying the shortcut]

Comment: Do you have a Magic Trackpad? [Three finger gestures](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/158897/5472) might work as well. https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/129755/5472